# Force Repository to return CustomClass type instead of Object type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, php-7, return-type

In my project with Symfony 4, Doctrine 2 and PHP 7.2, I have an entity called **Location** and a **LocationRepository** (which extends from Doctrine's ServiceEntityRepository).

I'm implementing a *findLocationByUuid* method in which given a string, returns a Location:

```
public function getLocationByUuid(string $uuid): Location
{
    $location = $this->findOneBy(['uuid' => $uuid]);

    if (null == $location) {
        throw new LocationNotFoundException();
    }

    return $location;
}
```

Since Doctrine's *findOneBy* method returns an *Object*, what would be the best way to strictly fit my return type declaration in the method and return a *Location* instead of an *Object*? Should I just assume this Object has the same behaviour than my Locations and declare Object as the return type?

Comment: LocationRepository :: findOneBy will always return a Location assuming one is found.  No need to worry about it returning something else.  It is just the way Doctrine Repositories work.  I suppose if your IDE is complaining then you could always typecast it.

Comment: @Cerad exactly. I could just ignore my IDE answering 'yes' to my second question, but still doesn't look nice to me. Checking the *instandeof* the object would be a solution, but it seems a bit useless. Casting custom classes in PHP it's quite tricky and dirty, I wouldn't consider it clean.

Comment: To quiet down your IDE, you can add `@method findOneby(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null): ?Location` to the DocBLock of your repository class.

Comment: Actually by type casting I meant more like "/** @var Location */" which tells the IDE you have a Location object.  Though I don't see why $location = (Location) $this->findOneBy would not work.  But '@var' should be all you need.

Comment: @Cerad in PHP you can only cast to primitive types. `$location = (Location) $this->findOneBy` is not valid.

Comment: Fair enough.  So use the doc notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony 4 **./bin/console make:entity** command creates entity & repository classes. Repository class has methods annotated, as per example, so your problem should be solved

```
/**
 * @method TinyPuppy|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method TinyPuppy|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method TinyPuppy[]    findAll()
 * @method TinyPuppy[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class TinyPuppyRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
```

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine's `findOneBy` is generic, so it cannot enforce `Location` as the return type. What I would do, in your case, is that instead of checking if the location is null, I'd check if it is an instance of `Location` so:

```
if (!$location instanceof Location) {
    throw new LocationNotFoundException();
}
```

This way you can be sure that if your method returns something, it's `Location`

Comment: Doctrines `findOneBy` either returns an object of the specified type or `null` so your code is behaving identical to OPs (although, when comparing to `null` I'd use `===` instead of `==` - but most of the time that's personal preference).